# Best way to check if object is out of bounds in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

What is the best practice to check if an object exists (is within bounds) at a specific index in an Array?

It would be nice to have it as simple as this, but that is unfortunately not possible:

```
let testArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

if let result = testArray[6] {
    println("Result: \(result)")
}
else {
    println("Result does not exist. Out of bounds.")
}
```

Will I have to check against the total count?

Thank you!

Comment: yes, check the count

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also make an extension to Array, so you will be able to check with if-let:

```
extension Array {
    func at(index: Int) -> Element? {
        if index < 0 || index > self.count - 1 {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index]
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3]

if let value = arr.at(index: 2) {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: use of undeclared type T?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta thanks for pointing out this was outdated, code updated. :)

Comment: Thanks ! Cheers ~~

Comment: Awesome for simple solution

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `~=` operator in conjunction with the `indices` function, which is a shortcut for creating a range of the full index range of a container:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let idx = 3  // one past the end

if indices(a) ~= idx {
    println("within")
}
else {
    println("without")
}
```

The one thing to note is this works with any kind of container that has a comparable index, not just ones like array that have integer indices.  Thinking of indices as numbers is generally a good habit to get out of, since it helps you think more generally about algorithms on containers without these indices, such as strings or dictionaries:

```
let s = "abc"
let idx = s.endIndex

idx < count(s)  // this won't compile

idx < s.startIndex  // but this will

// and so will this
if indices(s) ~= idx {
    println("within")
}
else {
    println("without")
}
```

The more general your algorithms, the more chance you will be able to factor them out into generics and increase re-use.

Comment: That is one 'ugly' operator; looking like it assigns the `lhs` with the result of `lhs ~ rhs` - like other `<op>=` operators.

Comment: Agree, I think it's awk-inspired.  ~== would be better IMHO.

Comment: Or even better, `Range` would have a contains operator, but unfortunately that wouldn't be able to take advantage of the comparator as range's indices are unconstrained.

Comment: `indices(a)` is deprecated. Use `a.indices` instead. – Anyway, I really like this solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new (neat) way to do it in Swift:

`array.indices.contains(index)`

Comment: CAREFUL- contains(_:) complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

@alkku has it but for simplicity and using the most underused syntactic form in all languages `?:`:

```
extension Array {
    func atIndex(index: Int) -> T? {
      return (0 <= index && index < self.count
              ? self[index]
              : nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check if object index used should be greater or equal to zero and should be less total count of array** like this :

```
//Here index is object you want for
if(index >= 0 && index < [yourArray count])
{
   //inside of array
}
else
{
   //out of bound
}
```

Comment: I think `<=` needs to be `>=`.

Comment: That's Objective-C. You probably meant `if index < testArray.count { ... }` :)

Comment: Also even in obj c, subtracting one then using <= makes no sense.

Comment: There is still an error in the first sentence "should be less than or equal to total count of array" , it should be "should be less than  total count of array"

Answer (score -1):

To check whether or not an index is inside the bounds of an array in swift you would use

```
if index < testArray.count {
    //index is inside bounds
} else {
    //index is outside bounds
}
```